# Rails 5: AJAX modal window for namespaced controller

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm trying to implement code from [this great tutorial of AJAX modal](http://www.benkirane.ch/ajax-bootstrap-modals-rails). It works like charm on regular controllers, however **it does not work when I have namespaced** one.

My */config/routes.rb* looks like this:

```
# Routes for campaigns
  namespace :campaigns do
    resources :campaigns, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  end

  get  '/campaigns', to: 'campaigns/campaigns#index'
```

In */views/campaigns/campaigns/index.html.erb*

```
...
<%= link_to 'New campaign', new_campaigns_campaign_path,
 remote: true, class: 'btn btn-primary btn-small' %>
...
```

In */views/campaigns/campaigns/_form.html.erb*

```
...
<%= form_for @campaign, remote: true, html: { role: 'form' } do |f| %>
...
```

My */views/campaigns/campaigns/new.js.erb*

```
// Add the dialog title
$('#dialog h3').html("<i class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></i> Add New Campaign");

// Render the new form
$('.modal-body').html('<%= j render("form") %>');

// Show the dynamic dialog
$('#dialog').modal("show");

// Set focus to the first element
$('#dialog').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $('.first_input').focus()
  })
```

and */views/campaigns/campaigns/create.js.erb*

```
$('#dialog').modal('toggle');
$('#campaigns').append('<%= j render (@campaign) %>')
```

are just like from the tutorial.

*controllers/campaigns/campaigns_controller.rb* is similar as in the tutorial, too:

```
#New campaign dialog
  def new
    edit_create_campaigns
    @campaign = current_user.campaigns.new
  end

  #Create campaign
  def create
    edit_create_campaigns
    @campaign = current_user.campaigns.create!(campaign_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @campaign.save
        format.json { head :no_content }
        format.js
      else
        format.json { render json: @campaign.errors.full_messages,
                            status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Error I'm getting in terminal:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `campaign_campaigns_index_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fd730c95ba8>:0x007fd762d32110>
```

**It seems Rails is trying to find path I don't have. How to fix this and make it work with my namespace model, please? Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute command `rake routes` and check if `campaign_campaigns_index_path` is there. If not, maybe you have misspelled it.

**EDIT**: Command `rake route` returns all available routes that can be called with `url`(and `_path`) helper.

**EDIT**: Well, you could rename the nested directory to `campaign`(singular), and don't forget to rename the class too `Campaign::CampaignsController < ....` That would be the cleaner way.

Comment: I've checked and I don't have such route. I think due to Rails convention that particular route is called from `_form.html.erb` partial. As mentioned - without namespaced controller it works, which leads me to assumption there is something related with namespaced controller and particular routing.

Comment: Well, you can always monkey patch it. `get  '/campaigns', to: 'campaigns/campaigns#index', as: :campaign_campaigns_index`.

Comment: I know, monkey patch works :) It's just I was thinking if there is some other solution.

Comment: Well, you could rename the nested directory to `campaign`(singular), and don't forget to rename the class too `Campaign::CampaignsController < ...`. That would be the cleaner way.

Comment: Thanks, nice :) If you edit your answer, I'll be happy to up-vote it.